# og:image not found when share on linkedin

Tags: metadata, share

i have a problem on the og:image meta. when I shared it on Facebook, the image of the article was read. However, when I shared it on LinkedIn, the image couldn't be read, even I checked on LinkedIn post inspector og: the image was not found. Maybe you guys know the solution?

I have created a meta like this

```
<meta property="og:title" name="title" class="title" content="<?= @$title ?? 'Digital Business Review' ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" name="image" class="image" content="<?= @$image ?? base_url() . 'storage/icons/logo_colored.png' ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="<?= htmlspecialchars(@$desc ?? '') ?>">
<meta property="og:url" name="uri" class="uri" content="<?= @$uri ?? base_url() ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Website">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?= @$image ?? base_url() . 'storage/icons/logo_colored.png' ?>" />
<link rel="image_src" href="<?= @$image ?? base_url() . 'storage/icons/logo_colored.png' ?>">
```

Comment: Try to append a "version" to the URL you are testing e.g. `www.example.com/blog/my-blog?v=42`. These crawlers can have a hard cache if they crawled the page before you've added the `og:image`

Comment: I've tried it, but still the preview image doesn't appear on LinkedIn. When I tried to inspect the browser, the URL to the article image appeared.